# open msaccess as swarm

Tags: multithreading, ms-access, vba

We all know that ms access is not multitreaded so when msacces runs a long query it hangs waiting to the query to be completed. what i want is open from access an new instance of access to run a query or run vba code in background. after running it needs to kit itself after it turns back the results (maybe though the sql server background)

i have seen something before in excel but i wonder if it is posible to do in access

the excel variant is here [excel swarm][1

UPDate

i open access with the folowing code

```
Dim appAccess As Object  
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")  
Call appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase( _ "D:\test.accdb")
appAccess.UserControl = True 
Set appAccess = Nothing
```

the target access db is preformatted with a loop as test with is started when access opens. the problem is that the souce access hangs during starting ans running of the target access.
i can use the timer to give it a delayed start and then its working.

the main problem is how can i stat a not preformated access db, create things like vba code, querys odbc connections etc and run it without the source db being hanging.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this from a shell command to another VBA host, say excel, which could trigger the event.  This is a class, where the properties of DB path and Query name are passed in, then GO is executed, it uses the Execute Complete event of the DBs ADO connection, I've coded it to create an Excel instance and populate with the results.

Ive not tested this fully as in the middle of something, but i'll test fully at lunch and edit as req'd, but a starting point

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents c As ADODB.Connection
Private strDBPath As String
Private strQueryToRun As String

Public Property Let DBPath(strPath As String)
    strDBPath = strPath
End Property

Public Property Let QueryToRun(strQuery As String)
    strQueryToRun = strQuery
End Property

Public Function GO()

Dim a As New Access.Application
a.OpenCurrentDatabase strDBPath, False

Set c = a.CurrentProject.Connection
c.EXECUTE strQueryToRun

a.CloseCurrentDatabase

a.Quit

Set a = Nothing

End Function

Private Sub c_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, _
                        ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)

    '   what to do with the results?

    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook

    xl.Visible = True
    Set xlWb = xl.Workbooks.Add
    xlWb.Sheets(1).Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset pRecordset

End Sub
```

Comment: looks great but i cant get it work. for now i must first do another job so this must wait for some time

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

Use command *Shell* to open another instance of Access - and add command line parameters Access to hold info about which queries to run.